# Disable Magento 2 invoice

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping, invoice, order-status

I want to set the order status from `pending` to `complete`after it got shipped out without creating an invoice.

Reason for this is, that we create invoices with our ERP. If we keep the Magento 2 invoices enabled, the customer would have two invoices with two different order numbers.

How can I disable the invoice in Magento 2 or change its status to `complete`?

Comment: do you got any solution for this?